# May I post a question about commissioning and finding someone to build a custom keyboard here?

Tags: support, specific-question

May I ask this at Hardware beta?

- How do I commission and find someone to build a custom keyboard?

See [Need light touch keyboard for neuro problems](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16565/10253)

Also, may I not set a bounty on this site?

Comment: I'm kinda mixed on this, I do know there's folks who will build 'custom' keyboards, and there's folks who literally build bespoke input devices - slaw device comes to mind. I also feel like you need to talk to folks who know keyboards to get a better idea of the problem space and budget. You might be able to 'simply' buy a keyboard with replacable key switches and slowly swap out switches to your liking, which is a broader problem scope

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62681112#62681112 bit of a conversation on the topic. I'm a bit of a keyboard nerd, though not 'obsessive' so I might be able to give basic information on the problem domain :D

Answer (score 2):

It's my understanding based on the [Help Center](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) that:

> we can help for recommendations of single, specific components

... and from the [on-topic page](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that:

> your question should be:
>
> - a request for a product recommendation
> - a request for information that will lead to a product decision

... which I would interpret to be just short of "How do I commission and find someone to...", so I think the answer here would be: no.

Re: your question on bounties, [You cannot create bounties on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77687/307535), if you're asking about bountying a question here on the Meta site. If you're unable to start a bounty on the [main site](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), it might be worth opening a separate [support](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) question for that, as my interpretation of the Help Center is that you'd need a minimum of 75 reputation for the [bounty privilege](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) -- which you have at the moment. There are some other criteria listed in the [What is a bounty?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) Help Center article, such as:

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

... which would theoretically take you below the 75 reputation threshold after you set the bounty, but that shouldn't prevent you from creating that bounty. If you're having this problem (placing a bounty on the Main site), please open a separate Meta question so that we can dig into the details.